SCD type 2 implementation (Postgres)
I'm trying to implement SCD2 in my project but i'm facing an issue
It won't let me insert the data from source.
I have a record of employee named Jack Rivera



emp_id
emp_name
position_id
source_id
start_dt
end_dt
is_active




1
Jack Rivera
2
some_src
2024-08-06
9999-12-31
TRUE



In my dataset I promoted him from Shop Assistant (id 2) to Sales Associate (id1)
So i want it to look like this



emp_id
emp_name
position_id
source_id
start_dt
end_dt
is_active




1
Jack Rivera
2
some_src
2024-08-06
2024-08-06
FALSE


1
Jack Rivera
1
some_src
2024-08-06
9999-12-31
TRUE



This code correctly finds and updates the row that is that was changed
It correctly identifies row in employee table and changes employee's status to FALSE
WITH srs_update AS (
    SELECT 
        srs.employee_name || ' - ' || srs.store_location AS unique_name,
        srs.employee_position,
        cp.employee_position_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY srs.employee_name, srs.store_location 
            ORDER BY 
                CASE
                    WHEN srs.transaction_date ~ '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}' THEN TO_DATE(srs.transaction_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                    ELSE COALESCE(TO_DATE(srs.transaction_date, 'DD-MM-YY'), TO_DATE(srs.transaction_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY'))
                END DESC
        ) AS row_num
    FROM  sa_offline_retail_sales.src_offline_sales srs 
    JOIN  bl_3nf.ce_positions cp ON srs.employee_position = cp.employee_position  AND 
            cp.source_entity = 'SRC_OFFLINE_SALES'  AND 
            cp.source_system = 'SA_OFFLINE_RETAIL_SALES' 
) 
    UPDATE bl_3nf.ce_employees_scd ces
    SET is_active = FALSE,
        end_dt = current_date
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM srs_update AS s
        WHERE s.unique_name = ces.employee_source_id
          AND s.employee_position_id != ces.employee_position_id AND 
          s.row_num = 1
    ) AND 
    ces.is_active = TRUE ;

The problem starts when I try to insert data from source where I promoted this employee
INSERT INTO bl_3nf.ce_employees_scd(
        employee_id,
        employee_name,
        employee_position_id,
        source_system,
        source_entity,
        employee_source_id,
        start_dt,
        end_dt,
        is_active,
        insert_dt
    )
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN t.employee_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN t.employee_id
            ELSE NEXTVAL('bl_3nf.seq_employees')
            END AS employee_id,
        srs.employee_name,
        cp.employee_position_id,
        'SA_OFFLINE_RETAIL_SALES' AS source_system,
        'SRC_OFFLINE_SALES' AS source_entity,
        srs.employee_name || ' - ' || srs.store_location  AS employee_source_id,
        current_date + 3 AS start_dt,
        '9999-12-31'::date AS end_dt,
        TRUE,
        current_date
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT employee_position,
                        employee_name,
                        store_location
        FROM sa_offline_retail_sales.src_offline_sales) srs
    LEFT JOIN bl_3nf.ce_positions cp ON srs.employee_position = cp.employee_position AND
            cp.source_system = 'SA_OFFLINE_RETAIL_SALES' AND
            cp.source_entity = 'SRC_OFFLINE_SALES'
    LEFT JOIN bl_3nf.ce_employees_scd t ON srs.employee_name = t.employee_name AND 
            t.source_system = 'SA_OFFLINE_RETAIL_SALES' AND
            t.source_entity = 'SRC_OFFLINE_SALES'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM bl_3nf.ce_employees_scd ces
        WHERE ces.employee_position_id = cp.employee_position_id AND
            ces.employee_name = srs.employee_name AND
            ces.source_system = 'SA_OFFLINE_RETAIL_SALES' AND
            ces.source_entity = 'SRC_OFFLINE_SALES' AND 
            ces.is_active = TRUE);

I even wrote start_dt as current_date + 3, so employees table doest have this date
But it results to this:
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ce_employees_scd_pkey"
  Detail: Key (employee_id, start_dt)=(1, 2024-08-09) already exists.

After checking table I do not have any records with id 1 and start_dt 2024-08-09.
Can someone help with this, i'm just getting desperate trying to solve this and make my scd2 work.
Any help is appreciated!

Okay, I managed to solve this by taking out and changing  ces.is_active = TRUE from WHERE NOT EXISTS clause. So I was able to insert and it did not give any errors

I think it would benefit when we know how your unique constraint, named ce_employees_scd_pkey, is defined.

First time when you are inserting data which does not exist won't be having is_active = TRUE. So it should not exists in SELECT statement in WHERE NOT EXISTS
INSERT INTO bl_3nf.ce_employees_scd(
        employee_id,
        employee_name,
        employee_position_id,
        source_system,
        source_entity,
        employee_source_id,
        start_dt,
        end_dt,
        is_active,
        insert_dt
    )
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN t.employee_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN t.employee_id
            ELSE NEXTVAL('bl_3nf.seq_employees')
            END AS employee_id,
        srs.employee_name,
        cp.employee_position_id,
        'SA_OFFLINE_RETAIL_SALES' AS source_system,
        'SRC_OFFLINE_SALES' AS source_entity,
        srs.employee_name || ' - ' || srs.store_location  AS employee_source_id,
        current_date + 3 AS start_dt,
        '9999-12-31'::date AS end_dt,
        TRUE,
        current_date
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT employee_position,
                        employee_name,
                        store_location
        FROM sa_offline_retail_sales.src_offline_sales) srs
    LEFT JOIN bl_3nf.ce_positions cp ON srs.employee_position = cp.employee_position AND
            cp.source_system = 'SA_OFFLINE_RETAIL_SALES' AND
            cp.source_entity = 'SRC_OFFLINE_SALES'
    LEFT JOIN bl_3nf.ce_employees_scd t ON srs.employee_name = t.employee_name AND 
            t.source_system = 'SA_OFFLINE_RETAIL_SALES' AND
            t.source_entity = 'SRC_OFFLINE_SALES'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM bl_3nf.ce_employees_scd ces
        WHERE ces.employee_position_id = cp.employee_position_id AND
            ces.employee_name = srs.employee_name AND
            ces.source_system = 'SA_OFFLINE_RETAIL_SALES' AND
            ces.source_entity = 'SRC_OFFLINE_SALES');

